# AVPlayer -- Observing rate to toggle play/pause buttons

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm using AVPlayer and I'm simply trying to toggle my play/pause button correctly. I can't just toggle based on user action because I'm starting/stopping the player automatically at times.

So I'm observing the `rate` key of the AVPlayer, and when a notification is sent, I check the `rate`.

- If 0, then I show the "play" button. (Player is paused)
- If 1, then I show the "pause" button. (Player is playing)

---

This works perfectly except for one situation. When the app goes to background and then becomes active again, the rate first goes to "1" and then to "0". So the button goes from "pause" to "play".

However, the video keeps playing, but I never get another `rate` notification of "1".

I even added this to code block that observes `rate`:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(logRate) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
```

I'm just checking the rate again 3 seconds after the last "0" rate change was observed. The video is still playing but the rate is still "0".

---

Does anyone know either:
1. Why this would happen?
2. Is there a better way to observe if an AVPlayer is playing or paused besides `rate`?

Comment: Can't you observe the awake notification? 
I had a bug with similar but it was actually a corrupt memory bug, resetting the device made it work normally again. 

If you get a call while audio is playing, it will screw up audio for the whole app, from any media playing at same moment.

Comment: @StephenJ Which awake notification are you talking about?

Comment: @StephenJ Check out my limited answer - was this something to what you were experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why this is happening but I did find an isolated fix that also might help someone more knowledgeable figure this out.

I discovered that if I "paused" the player before going to background, when I went to foreground and resumed "play" I never got the rate going from "1" to "0". It went to "1" and stayed there.

So for my case I just added an observation for:

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(willResignActive:) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
```

and I now pause the player in `willResignActive:`.

---

What this does tell me is that going to background while the `AVPlayer` is playing puts the `AVPlayer` in a state that caused the error I asked about, but I don't know any further details right now.